# How to Post attachments to twitter using twitter API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

Can anyone suggest me how to post attachments to twitter using twitter API,
 I tried this it is working but ,our attachments has not been posted like images and links ..

my code is like this

```
TwitterRequest *t=[[TwitterRequest alloc] init];
    t.username=self.username.text;
    t.password=self.password.text;
[t statuses_update:@"text that is posted to twitter" delegate:self requestSelector:@selector(status_updateCallback:)];
```

Comment: Twitter doesn't support "attachments". It supports plain text messages, twitter clients (including the main twitter website) detect URIs and hyperlink them.

Comment: You can post attachments to Twitter?

Answer (score 3):

For images, you have to use another service, like Twitpic:

http://twitpic.com/api.do

Comment: Twitter also Supports uploading Images. You dont have to use another service like twitpic